# Compiling a program that requires both python.h and cl.h

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to compile a program that uses both `python.h` and `cl.h` using: `gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -I/home/arm/bin/c/hashcat/deps/OpenCL-Headers/CL -lOpenCL cpu_md4.c -o cpu_md4`, however when I run this I get the following:

```
arm@arm-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/dagon/bin/attacks/cpu_attack$ gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -I/home/arm/bin/c/hashcat/deps/OpenCL-Headers/CL -lOpenCL cpu_md4.c -o cpu_md4
In file included from types.h:889:0,
                 from cpu_md4.c:10:
ext_OpenCL.h:15:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CL/cl.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
arm@arm-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/dagon/bin/attacks/cpu_attack$
```

How I got the `cl.h` directory was doing this:

```
arm@arm-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/dagon/bin/attacks/cpu_attack$ find / -iname cl.h 2>/dev/null
/home/arm/bin/c/hashcat/deps/OpenCL-Headers/CL/cl.h
```

How can I compile this application using the header files that I already have?

Comment: Your -I path specified CL as last directory, but your include-directive specifies CL/cl.h. Try to remove one of them

Comment: @radical7 awh, that makes more sense. Lol it's going to be pretty interesting once I get it up and running, thank you!

Comment: @BjornA. has the simplest solution - I missed that little `CL` in the `-include` directive on your compile line